# Ubuntu Studio (20.04): studio-controls has unexpectedly stopped working

Tags: ubuntu-studio

Running Xubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
Ubuntu Studio installed via `ubuntustudio-installer` with backports activated. For several months I've been running `studio-controls` without problem.  Yesterday it ran fine.  Today it doesn't but generates the following when run in a terminal:

```
$ studio-controls
install path: /usr
Config file: /home/user/.config/autojack/autojack.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 1881, in <module>
    us = StudioControls()
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 623, in __init__
    self.refresh_net(self.znetbridge)
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 1494, in refresh_net
    if not (os.path.isfile(znj) and os.access(znj, os.X_OK)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
    st = os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
$
```

Never had this problem before.  Any ideas?  Any further information needed?

Answer (score 1):

Using Synpatic Package Manager, I removed `studio-controls`. Synaptic informed me that it will also remove `ubuntustudio-installer`.  After removing those two packages.  I then reinstalled `ubuntustudio-installer`. Installing `ubuntustudio-installer` also installs `studio-controls`. Then I executed `studio-controls`, which now worked as expected.  All is well.